# Thunderbird folder size limit

Tags: thunderbird

**What is the limit on the size of a Thunderbird folder?** I read [this page on mozillazine.org](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Limits_-_Thunderbird#Folders_and_messages), but it seemed to contradict itself several times. I'm still confused. Is it 4GB or not?

My Gmail account is nearing 4GB on All Mail and I want to know if there will be a problem before it happens. My computer is Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: What version of Thunderbird are you using? 24.2.0?  Storing the data in mbox format seems to have more issues that in the maildir format.  Using maildir each message is stored in an individual file so in theory the only limit should be the file system. http://jaisejames.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/to-activate-maildir-in-thunderbird/

Comment: @cybernard Maildir is buggy and not supported yet.

Comment: Yet, if he wants to continue using Thunderbird and exceed 4GB limit it seems the only way 100% safe or not.  I don't know what bugs it may have, but fundamentally it is a solid foundation.  Each email is stored in it own file and is stored in folders thus the only limits are the ones of the native filesystem.  As long as a unique file name is maintained for each email the actual storage of the email is safe.

Comment: On the original persons question link.  Under **folders and messages** The third paragraph suggests that it may become the default in Thunderbird 24.  This suggests that the bugs are expected to either already be fixed or to be fixed in the near future.